# Need SQL for Comparing Incoming Records to Existing Ones on Specific Criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

Afternoon Folks,

I’ve searched these forums and not found quite what I was looking for, so I’m hoping with a detailed request someone can point me in the right direction. I’m new to SQL (Oracle) and am trying to do some comparing between two databases. I’ll lay out the context briefly, and then get into the particulars:

We get files full of personal data for people (names, DoB, addresses, etc). Some of them are already in our database, and others are not. A lot of people are in our database but their new data is not a perfect match, e.g. we have them as “Billy” and they contact us again as “William”. We have established some criteria for comparing imperfect matches, and need to generate reports that will let us compare incoming records to potential matches based on the criteria below. We also have some old data in our system, with unique identifiers (a nine-digit number) and would like the search to exclude a range of values that are unlikely to produce actual matches.

1. Anyone in our database with the same SSN (ironically, we’ve found this to be an inconsistent way of identifying people!).
2. Anyone who matches on the first 10 characters or fewer of the last name and the first 10 characters or fewer of the city—“Alexandre” would be a potential match for “Alexandretta”, but “Johnsonville” would not be a match for “Johnson”. (This captures people like Billy/William from above.)
3. Anyone who matches on the first 5 characters or fewer of the first names and the first 10 characters or fewer of the last name—“Al Stevens” would be a potential match for “Albert Stevenson”.

Thanks in advance,
Glen

Comment: Are these condition connected by AND or OR. I mean do all of the conditions have to be true or only one of them?

Comment: I recommend you look up how to use `impdp` and how to write SQL statements. If you need more information then I recommend you to ask more detailed questions. For example, "Anyone in our database with the same SSN". To ask that question, you would provide the DDL for the tables involved in that query, give some sample data, and then show the SQL statement that you've tried that doesn't do exactly what you want. Show what you get and what you want.